# Multi-line representation in a XML + XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I make a XML with XSLT tranformation and sometimes the XML passed data should be aligned on more lines. 
The point is that this doesn't happens in case I write multi-lines in XML and also if I try to replace new line character (\n) with "br" html tag. 

 In the transformation process the br tag seems to be ignored.

```
 // xml part  
 <description>
 two of our <br/> famous Belgian Waffles<br/>
 with plenty of real maple syrup
 </description> 

 // xslt part
 <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
```

Inserting "br" tag in .xslt file it works but it's not suitable for my case - a dynamic behavior of inserting new line tag.

Do you know a workaround to generate html with multi-lines but with the data such "new line" character coming from .xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the **xsl:value-of** element returns all the text elements in the description element. Since the **br** tags are no text elements these are ignored and not copied to the html.

use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="description"/>
```

The **xsl:copy-of** copies the complete subtree, text and all embedded elements. So the **br** tags will be preserved in the output.